# 27" x 1 1/4" back flip flop wheel or track wheel(rear)

Tags: fixed-gear, rear-wheel, flip-flop-hub

I'm looking for a good wheel, I don't know much about brands and what's reputable.  I'm replacing my back wheel because it's a suicide hub set up by a local bike shop(cheap short term fix)

I'm wanting to replace my back wheel without having to replace my tire and innertube so I need to match the current size.  any advice, or links to a wheel to buy will be very appreciated.

Current tyre size is 32-630.

Comment: Specific product recommendations are off topic for SE.  Instead you should search online traders like wiggle or CRC, and ask your local bike shop directly for what they have in stock/can get.

Answer (score 1):

The critical measurements are that you have to match the rim diameter to your brakes, and the width of your hub to whatever your frame needs.

A *27" wheel* may be several different sizes.  Its best to use the ETRTO number which is 622-xx for a 700c wheel and 630-xx or 635-xx are nominal 27 inch.

So your existing tyre/tube will fit because the new wheel's rim has to be the same size as the old one.  Nothing else will do unless you want to risk needing a brake replacement.  If you have disk brakes then its a little more forgiving, but still not a good idea.

Also the new rim's internal width should be pretty similar to the width of the old rim.

---

If your existing rim's okay then you might choose to replace the hub and rebuild the wheel.  Its possible you need shorter/longer spokes at this point, and there's certainly no cost saving over a complete wheel if you can find one.

Comment: there are no rear brakes, how do I find the ETRTO number? I want to order the part without going to a shop.

Comment: @Alex4nder it will be written on the sidewall of the tyre.  Anything made in the last couple decades will have this sizing code.  If its over 2 decades old then degradation sets in and it should also be replaced for that reason.  Format of the number will be    622-xx or   xx-622     or  630 or 635 or similar.  The 2 digit number is the tyre width in mm and the 3 digit number is the diameter in mm.

Comment: what I'm seeing is (32-630)

Comment: OK you do not have a 700c wheel which would be 622... instead you have one of the several 27 inch wheel sizes.   Given that its a fixed speed and there are no rim brakes, you could reasonably buy a 700c wheel and a new tyre/tube.   The existing tubes will work fine for both size wheels if the valve is the same sort.

Comment: is this the only option for me?  I don't prefer the look of 2 different sized wheels, and I can't afford a wheel set right now..  does no one make fixed wheels in the size that I have? I've come across a few online but I'm not so sure about the quality of them.

Comment: This is one i've found https://www.harriscyclery.net/product/harris-cyclery-27-weinmann-fixed-gear-rear-wheel-673.htm

Comment: @Alex4nder It does say 630 in the category, so that's a match.  It is drilled for a Schrader valve (car sized valve) and has an OLD of 120mm.  That's the other thing for you to check - a ruler between the two rear dropouts will be accurate enough.   126mm is the next common size up from 120, then 130mm, then 135mm.  The only other consideration is your weight - if you're over 80 kilos you might consider the 36 spoke version not the 32 spoke version linked.  Given its a fixie, more spokes will help with resisting the braking force too.

Comment: @Criggie 622 is 28" or 29", 635 is always 28" and 27" clincher is always 630.

Comment: @ojs yep - the ETRTO number is always right. everything else is unreliable.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this will be compatible, right?   https://www.worldwidecyclery.com/products/quality-wheels-rear-wheel-track-27-32h-sun-cr-18-polished-formula-track-fixed-free-silver-dt-industry-silver

Comment: That is identical in spec to the harris cyclery link.  32 spoke, 120mm OLD, 630mm diameter.